# Why does my program hang when opening a mkfifo-ed pipe?

Tags: c++, c, mkfifo

I use mkfifo to create a named pipe.
Then I use the following program to open it. However, the program hangs at the line "fopen". Is there something wrong here?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char* line = "hello, world!";
FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "rw");
fprintf(fp, line);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Try passing `"w"` as the mode to fopen. `"rw"` is not a valid mode argument for `fopen`, and even if it was, you probably don't want to both read and write to the FIFO in the same process (although it is possible, see below).

<sup>As an aside, the correct mode argument for opening a file for both reading and writing is either `"r+"` or `"w+"` (see the answers to [this question for the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113919/difference-between-r-and-w-in-fopen)).</sup>

This program will correctly write to the FIFO:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "Hello, world!\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `fopen` in the above program will block until the FIFO is opened for reading. When it blocks, run this in another terminal:

```
$ cat /tmp/myFIFO
Hello, world!
$
```

The reason why it blocks is because `fopen` does not pass `O_NONBLOCK` to `open`:

```
$ strace -P /tmp/myFIFO ./a.out
open("/tmp/myFIFO", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
...
```

### Some background on how FIFOs are opened

Read-only, without `O_NONBLOCK`: `open` blocks until another process opens the FIFO for writing. This is the behavior when using `fopen` with mode argument `"r"`.

Write-only, without `O_NONBLOCK`: `open` blocks until another process opens the FIFO for reading. This is the behavior when using `fopen` with mode argument `"w"`.

Read-only, with `O_NONBLOCK`: `open` returns immediately.

Write-only, with `O_NONBLOCK`: `open` returns an error with `errno` set to `ENXIO` unless another process has the FIFO open for reading.

<sup>Info from "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment" by W. Richard Stevens.</sup>

### Opening a FIFO for read *and* write

Opening a FIFO for reading and writing within the same process is also possible with Linux. The [Linux FIFO man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) states:

> Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in
>   blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined.
>   This can be used to open a FIFO for writing while there are no readers
>   available.  A process that uses both ends of the connection in order
>   to communicate with itself should be very careful to avoid deadlocks.

Here's a program which writes to and reads from the same FIFO:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char buf[100] = {0};
    FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "r+");
    fprintf(fp, "Hello, world!\n");
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
    printf("%s", buf);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

It does not block, and returns immediately:

```
$ gcc fifo.c && ./a.out 
Hello, world!
```

Note that this is not portable and may not work on operating systems besides Linux.

Answer (score 13):

The process blocks until the other end of the pipe gets opened.