# Can't open() second file C

Tags: c

For some reason if I do a second open, it compiles but when I try to run it, it does nothing like it's locked. It's missing a lot of other functions, because it's a work in progress for a school project. If I remove one of the open(), the program runs just fine.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

#define INPUT "/tmp/father"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int fds;

    int fd;

    char mode[BUFFER_SIZE];

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    unlink(INPUT);

    mkfifo(INPUT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fputs("Argumentos invalidos\n", stderr);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY);

    if(fd == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't open pipe\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fds = open(INPUT, O_RDONLY);

    if(fds == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't open pipe\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        fgets(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin);

        sscanf(buffer,"%s", mode);      

        write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value from `unlink()` and `mkfifo()`.  Also, read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507810/why-does-my-program-hang-when-opening-a-mkfifo-ed-pipe and this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580013/how-do-i-perform-a-non-blocking-fopen-on-a-named-pipe-mkfifo?rq=1

Comment: Are you trying to open the same file twice? That may not be possible especially since you've got a write-handle open. You need to close() the handle to the file first.

Comment: On my other program I'm doing " int father = open("/tmp/father", O_WRONLY); " both /tmp/father and argv[1] are named pipes

Comment: You said it does nothing like it's locked, but how far does it get? The `fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);` will block until a line has been read from standard input. The `write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));` will block if there is no room left in the FIFO.

Comment: Hopefully, your other program doesn't unlink and create "/tmp/father" as well!

Comment: It doesn't unlink and create father ! It unlinks and create "/tmp/par-shell-in"

Comment: Look up the `perror` function.  It prints out error messages, which are likely to be very helpful to you.

Comment: the posted code manipulates the file system before checking the argc for a correct number of command line parameters.   Strongly suggest checking the parameters first and if the count is correct, then manipulate the file system.

Comment: when calling system functions, especially those that access items that are not under the programs control, like opening a file or creating a fifo node, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  When an error indication is returned from a system function, immediately call `perror()` to write to stderr with the enclosed text And the associated system error message.

Comment: when checking the command line parameter count (argc), if the count is not correct, then call printf() with a `USAGE`  statement and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: a write to a pipe will block until the read end is open'd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there's a problem? You are reading from stdin (the `fgets` at the bottom), and writing to the pipe. What you're missing is something reading from the pipe. So if in another terminal you type:

```
$ cat /tmp/father
```

then anything you type into your prog will appear there.

So, in one terminal I do:

```
$ ./test /tmp/father
line one
line two
```

And in the second terminal:

```
$ cat /tmp/father
```

and I see:

```
line one
line two
```

No?

P.S. You are doing `sscanf` to read from `buffer` and write to `mode`, then writing out the `buffer` string. Not that it matters, but you're not using `mode`.

Comment: if(strcmp(mode,"stats") == 0)
  {
   read(fds,buff,BUFFER_SIZE);

   printf("%s\n",buff);
  }

Comment: The argv[1] is /tmp/par-shell-in , created in another program. That other program creates the par-shell-in then redirects the stdin to that pipe. If it reads stats from that pipe (sent by the code above), writes to /tmp/father a string I need.

Comment: So I'm confused about what you're attempting. You write to the file specified in `argv[1]`, which is descriptor `fd`. You read characters from `stdin`, and write them to `fd`. Descriptor `fds` is the read side of your pipe, which you don't do anything with. If you specify `argv[1]` as /tmp/father, then you're writing to the write side of the pipe (but nothing is reading it -- thus the `cat` works)....